# How to update multiple columns with a single select query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let take a example, there are two tables as bellow.

```
OldData
-----------
    id
    name
    address

NewData
-----------
    nid
    name
    address
```

I want to update `OldData` table with `NewData` table.

For that purpose I am trying to use the following query:

```
UPDATE OldData SET (name, address) = (SELECT name, address FROM NewData WHERE nid = 234)
WHERE id = 123
```

But it gives a syntax error.

What is the proper way of doing what I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE OldData o, NewData n 
SET n.name = o.name, n.address = o.address 
where n.nid=234 and o.id=123;
```

Comment: It should be `SET o.name = n.name, o.address = n.address`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Update oldData set name = (select name from newData where nid = 234),address = (select address from newData where nid = 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
UPDATE OldData a,NewData b 
SET a.name = b.name , a.address = b.address 
WHERE a.id=123 AND b.nid = 234
```